# Passing Image through UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimage

I have an image in my RootViewController (which is selected from a UIImagePickerController), which I need to pass to a new view through a navigation controller.  I have the following code that I use to pass strings to the next view:

```
//Get strings
NSString *text1 = line1.text;
NSString *text2 = line2.text;
NSString *text3 = line3.text;
NSString *text4 = line4.text;

//Create an GeneratedViewController and initialise it with given data
GeneratedViewController *gController = [[GeneratedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GeneratedViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
gController.text1 = text1;
gController.text2 = text2;
gController.text3 = text3;
gController.text4 = text4;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gController animated:YES];
[gController release];
gController = nil;
```

How might I pass an image to the GeneratedViewController?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Why not give GeneratedViewController a UIImage property? You say you have the image already, so you can just set it to the new image property of GeneratedViewController.

Comment: @BoopMeister , sorry, should have been more clear, the image is selected from a UIImagePickerController in the RootViewController and saved to a variable.  I need to then transfer this selected image to the next view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to create a property of type UIImage on GeneratedViewController.
Then after creating and initializing the GeneratedViewController but before pushing it onto the navigationController you will need to set the image property on the gController to the selected image.

Answer (score 0):

- A property on the controller, just like the text is set
- In a method, or the initializer
- through a notification (NSNotificationCenter). This is a bit more advanced.
- Through delegation, where the first controller is a datasource delegate on the Generated Controller. This allows the second controller to get what it needs, whenever it wants.

Which method to use depends on how the controllers are created, when the image can change, and how many different pieces of data the second controller needs - one or two bits, properties work fine. More than that, I tend to use delegation.